# Bash script comparison is not working

Tags: bash

I am working on a bash script and for some reason the if statement is always coming true. If I run the following app and at the prompt I type yes and hit enter, here is what prints out:

```
The code will be checked out in the location the file is in, is this ok? (yes or no)
yes
yes
Stopping app
```

Here is what my code looks like. Am I missing something here?

```
echo "The code will be checked out in the location the file is in, is this ok? (yes or no)"

read answer

echo $answer

if [[ $answer -eq "no" ]] ; then
        echo "Stopping app"
        exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the `-eq`. `-eq` is for numeric comparisons. Use `=` instead,
so

```
[[ $answer = "no" ]]
```

instead of

```
[[ $answer -eq "no" ]]
```